# HTTP Error 503 on IIS 7.5 after SP Install

Tags: iis, windows-7

I have Windows 7 professional 32-bit with IIS 7.5 installed and configured. I installed the SP1 for Win 7 and since then the IIS is no more working. Even for simple queries like localhost/a.htm (where a.htm is a html file inside under c:\inetpub\wwwroot) leads me to the error:

```
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

The IIS worked fine up to SP1 (I have a lot of ASP.NET2/.NET 4 applications on it). I uninstalled the SP1, the same happens. What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: what does the eventlog report?

Comment: Just: "The Peer Name Resolution Protocol cloud did not start because the creation of the default identity failed with error code: 0x80630801." in the system view.

Comment: And a lot of "Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is provided [here](https://superuser.com/questions/250176/http-error-503-on-iis-7-5-after-sp-install) by squillman.

> Sounds like your app pool(s) is/are not starting. Open IIS Manager and click on Application Pools, then check the Status column and make sure the all say Started (or at least your DefaultAppPool says Started). If it's not started, right-click on the app pool and choose Start. If you get an error let us know what it is.

Answer (score 13):

I had this issue and it turned out to be that SP1 causes the "Load User Profile" setting on your Application Pools to be set to "True" causing IIS to use a Temp User Profile that doesn't have sufficient permissions.

To fix it I took the following steps:

1. Load up IIS
2. Click on Application Pools
3. Go to Advanced Settings
4. Scroll down to "Load User Profile" under the "Process Model" section
5. Set to "False"

Comment: This worked a treat for a similar issue I am having, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem after Win7 SP1 got installed. The problem in my case was Skype: that was listening in on ports 80 and 443 and thus blocking IIS. Told Skype not to do that (there is a checkbox for that in Settings | Advanced | Connection) and my sites worked again.

What the relation is between Skype forgetting that setting and the installation of SP1 (other than it happening at the same time) I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

At the command line, run (you might need to be administrator)

```
netsh http show urlacl
```

If any of those conflict with your IIS bindings, delete them with `netsh http delete urlacl`.

Per https://superuser.com/a/351628/62691

Answer (score 1):

I just googled the eventlog message for you and got this as a posible solution:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/932e85c6-b141-4bc5-8be7-daa7e0ff714b

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by andyvidual did not help. I realized that the default application pool had stopped. When I started it the error went away and I could display the issstart.htm. Then I checked the default app pool settings and noted that the Load User Profile was 'TRUE'. I changed it to 'FALSE' but the 503 error did not come back. I guess it is the stopped pool that was responsible.